# Intent en android

Tags: android

Gente tengo este pequeño problema con un intent que no se porque la app cuando la pruebo se cierra. Tengo esto en el MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_note);

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),AddNote.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
}
```

En la Activity AddNote tengo esto

```
public class AddNote extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText editText1,editText2;
    private Button buttonAdd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_note);

         editText1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titulo_text);
         editText2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descripcion_text);
         buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton_addNota);

         buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {

                if(editText1.getText().toString().equals("")||editText2.getText().toString().equals(""))
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Faltan Datos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    addNote();
             }
         });
    }
    public void addNote(){
        DbHelper admin = new DbHelper(this,"Notas",null,1);
        SQLiteDatabase database= admin.getWritableDatabase();
        String titulo= editText1.getText().toString();
        String descripcion= editText2.getText().toString();
        ContentValues registroValues= new ContentValues();
        registroValues.put("Titulo",titulo);
        registroValues.put("Description",descripcion);
        database.insert("Notas",null,registroValues);
        database.close();
        editText1.setText("");
        editText2.setText("");
        finish();
    }
}
```

Antes de Implementar los metodos e inicializar variables ya se me cerraba. No se porque se cierra. ayudaa!!

Comment: Hola Erio , al desarrollar en Android es importante revisar y en el caso de tu ptregunta, agregar el mensaje desplegado en el LogCat, esto puede ser una diferencia entre solucionar el problema en unos segundos o en días, saludos.

Comment: Gracias ya pude resolver el problema, al entrar al LogCat. Me sirvió de mucho gracias

Comment: Comenta como lo solucionaste. Esto le puede servir a otros

Comment: El problema es que hay que añadirlo obligado en el Manifest, ejemplo: <activity android:name=".AddNote"></activity>